# Jersey 'NoContent' response returns 200 instead of 204

Tags: java, rest, jersey-1.0

I am using Jersey (1.18) to build a REST API for my WebApplication. In a part of my code I have the following snippet.

```
return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(err_message).build();
```

where `Status` is an instance of `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.Status;`

According to Jersey Documentation `NO_CONTENT` should return a **204** code, instead of this, the http response has a header with **200** code.

> NO_CONTENT
>   public static final ClientResponse.Status NO_CONTENT
>   204 No Content, see HTTP/1.1 documentation.

I tried to change the aforementioned code to

```
return Response.noContent().entity(err_message).build();
```

But the issue still exists.
As a side note, using `NOT_FOUND` instead of `NO_CONTENT`, return a **404** header as expected.

Any suggestion on 'How can I return 204 code?', is this a bug or I am doing something wrong.

Note: Not a duplicate  of [Returning 200 response code instead of 204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344054/returning-200-response-code-instead-of-204)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107923/185034) which says,

> ...204 means "No Content", meaning that the response contains no
>   entity, but you put one in it. It's likely that Jersey is switching it
>   to a 200 for you, which is basically identical to a 204 except that it
>   contains a response entity.
>
> Finally, you can get 204 responses very simply by a couple of built-in
>   behaviors: void methods and null return values both map to a 204
>   response. Otherwise, simply return `Response.status(204).build()`.

In other words, if you want "NO_CONTENT" then don't include content in your response.

Comment: Beat me for a minute! Thanks for the quick answers. I have also concluded in the same thing

Answer (score 3):

After a little more digging I have found the problem. The [W3c Documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) gives a hint.

I am quoting

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

In my code I have `entity(err_message)`  which causes the problem. By removing it the **204** is returned correctly. I think somehow the Jersey or 'someone' casts the response to **200** since it has content.

**Update (02/05/2015)**

This [blog post](http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com.cy/2016/05/jersey-library-overwrites-200-response.html) link (posted earlier today as an answer and then deleted), gives some additional insights about situation. Based on the content of the blog post, whenever there is any content in the HTTP response the following method is invoked. This method sets the status code back to 200.

```
private void commitWrite() throws IOException {
   if (!isCommitted) {
       if (getStatus() == 204)
           setStatus(200);
       isCommitted = true;
       o = responseWriter.writeStatusAndHeaders(size, ContainerResponse.this);
   }
}
```

We can say that Jersey detects that since there is some content in the response, the status code was wrongly set to 204 and it changes it to the appropriate 200.